# Using an abstract class to satisfy an interface in php

Tags: php, class, interface, abstract

I want to use Amazon SNS to send text messages in my application. My only concern is, what happens if I decide I want to swap out Amazon SNS for another provider?

I have come up with the following solution but am unsure if this is best practise or if this has any repercussions in the future.

```
<?php

interface SMS {
    public function sendSMS($from, $to);
}

abstract class AmazonSNS {
    public function sendSMS($from, $to) {
        echo 'Message sent';
    }
}

class Notification extends AmazonSNS implements SMS {

}

$notification = new Notification;
$notification->sendSMS('xxxx', 'xxxx');
```

My thought process was that my application will only care about the *notification class* and that class will force whatever *abstract class* (service provider) I am using to implement the methods required by the *interfaces* (I might use an email interface as well). Using an abstract class also stops it from being instantiated directly, which would be undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

For me it is better to use

```
<?php

    interface Notification {
        public function notify($from, $to);
    }

    class AmazonSNSSmsNotification implements Notification {
        public function notify($from, $to) {
             //send notification using SMS
        }
    }

    class OtherProviderSmsNotification implements Notification {
        public function notify($from, $to) {
             //send notification using SMS from other provider
        }
    }

    class EmailNotification implements Notification {
        public function notify($from, $to) {
             //send notification using email
        }
    }
```

then you can swap implementation easily

```
function sendNotification(Notification $notifObj, $from, $to) {
    $notifObj.notify($from, $to);
}

sendNotification(new AmazonSNSSmsNotification(), $from, $to);
sendNotification(new OtherProviderSmsNotification(), $from, $to);
```

Comment: Because `Notification` is interface, then instance passed as first parameter must instance of `Notification` interface otherwise it will throw error.